# Kubernetes Blocked Mixed Active Content

Tags: http, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

**Issue:**

When working with K8's [Kubernetes] on development, I'm running into the issue where my Ingress/Nginx seems keep my client side (React) from pulling data from my API (Flask/Python).

**Details:**

The connection between the client and API is facilitated using an Environment Variable that we'll call `API_URL` for the sake of this post.  `API_URL` is used so that the Client knows which API routes to GET and POST.

On Minikube with K8's in dev, the Minikube IP that is provided forces http**s** from what I understand (or maybe it's ingress/nginx?).  The `API_URL` environment variable value is `value: api-cluster-ip-service`.  However, when I hit the dev site it's showing that this value gets assigned to http://localhost (not-https)

This causes: Blocked loading mixed active content “http://localhost/server/stuff".  As a result, I can't pull anything from my API.

**Question:**

Is there a recommended approach for this? Perhaps a way to turn https off on dev (I don't even know if that's possible)?  Or maybe I need a certificate for localhost? I'm fairly new to Kubernetes so any help is much appreciated!

**Ingress-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

**Ingress Namespace output**

```
kubectl get ing --all-namespaces
default     ingress-service   *       10.0.2.15   80      4d21h
```

Comment: Can you share your ingress yaml?

Comment: @Crou Yup!  added in an edit

Comment: @dizzy how did you deploy your ingress controller?

Comment: @c4f4t0r 
`Minikube > kubectl apply` is how I deployed the ingress server file to the cluster.
`minikube addons enable ingress` is how I turned it on.  No other configuration.  This is strictly for a dev environment. Let me know if that answers your question!

Comment: @dizzy kubectl get ing --all-namespaces

Comment: @c4f4t0r added in an edit above.  Let me know if that's enough info!

Comment: @dizzy, have you tried specifying the `host` in your .yaml? Also you can disable the redirect adding annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"`

Comment: I actually haven't tried modifying the host in the .yaml file. I'll give that a shot.  Thanks for the tip on disabling SSL.  Will try that as well and report back if that's the answer to this mess!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. What does this "mixed active content" error mean? Are you using websockets or something?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I honestly think it's a consequence of another database related error and I'm just seeing something else pop up in the console.  I'm seeing less of the error now that I've resolved that.  Will come back and update this issue if it corrects itself or persists after I make a couple more changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem...and the error message was fairly misleading.  On a local environment, my Client side talks to my API via http://localhost/api/.  However, I realized that because I was on Minikube, it's no longer on localhost (because Minikube has it's own IP). Once I changed my API_URL to http:// it began working immediately.

The only challenge here is that minikube, when stopped, changes the IP on each refresh, meaning I need to grab the IP and update the API_URL each time.  However, that's a separate question/answer.

**Summary:**

Changed my API_URL from http://localhost to the Minikube IP.  Began working immediately.